# Do you quote HTML5 attributes?

Tags: html, performance, standards

[Attribute quotes are **optional** in HTML5](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/syntax.html#unquoted).

What are the pros/cons to quoting them?

```
id=example                     <!--quotes optional-->
href=http://example.com        <!--quotes optional-->
class="example example-1"      <!--quotes required due to space-->
href="http://example.com/p=47" <!--quotes required due to '=' sign-->
```

Update: Added advantages based on the answers:

Advantages to quoting all attributes:

- all editors can deal with it properly
- more consistent
- better portability (easier to change doctype)
- easier to maintain (esp. if attributes might become empty)
- easier to 'find and replace' changes
- cleaner doc (if you think quotes improve readability)
- ?

Advantages to **omitting** optional quotes:

- slightly reduced filesize
- cleaner doc (if you prefer minimal text)
- ?

Comment: “Cleaner document”? eh, don’t think so.

Comment: I vote for Community Wiki'ing this, as it's subjective

Comment: See [HTML/XHTML advantages](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+xhtml+advantages) and [Get Ready for HTML5](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/get-ready-for-html-5/).

Comment: @konrad-rudolph updated question w/ clarification on 'cleaner'

Comment: @ryan we can't do that any more, a moderator may do it if they see fit. (Edit: they decided to close it instead - ah well :)

Comment: See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values for the exact rules on when quotes are required around attribute values, both in HTML and in CSS/JavaScript. I also made [a tool that will tell you if a given attribute value can be used without quotes or not](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#foo%7Cbar).

Comment: You can use single-quote marks (apostrophe) instead of double-quote. That makes working in many programming languages (Java etc.) easier.

Comment: I don't buy "more consistent". What's inconsistent about quoting attribute values if and only if you need to?

Comment: @HughW well, do you need quotes in `<link href=subdir/>`? Is the slash part of the URL or part of the tag structure?

Comment: What has that to do with html5? Did anything change there?

Comment: @RobertSiemer It's more in contrast to XHTML, which requires quotes and was popular before HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.4

Comment: So the answer to my question is: It has nothing to do with HTML_5_. Your question was more "Do you quote HTML attributes? -- I know you had to in XHTML."

Comment: For this kind of questions I can recommend https://vote4code.com/ :)

Comment: I've stumbled upon a very concerning matter in this subject by accident while minifying the output. I have a static site with a search form using the Taxonomy Terms Page as data-source, reading links and queueing URLs to request asynchronously and extract information later. But even though every single URL, requester and requested, are full-formed absolute URLs, both with SSL and under the same domain, the lack of quotes around the `href` attributes prevented my requests to complete, giving me the usual 'unsecured endpoint" message. I thought this could be of someone interest.

Comment: As for file size, when using Brotli compression, eliding quotes usually leads to slightly larger files. That's because the dictionary is built from websites that mostly had quoted attributes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'm in favour of always using quotes.

- It looks *way* cleaner and more consistent
- All editors can deal with it properly
- It's easier to maintain - you can edit values without breaking them because quotes are missing.

The few bytes you save in document size by dropping quotes where they are not needed are not worth mentioning (unless maybe you're Google's home page).

Comment: Good point about maintainability

Comment: Also if you edit dynamically it won't break attributes

Comment: I updated question with these—thanks :)

Comment: Even Google uses quoted values on their mainpage ;)

Comment: It's also worth to mention that even if you're Google's home page, it's the job of a script to reduce the filesize, not the author's.

Comment: And god forbid finding out what kind of breakages this will cause in old browsers or mobile browsers or some browser that doesn't know what you want. Taking one pass at reducing your JS complexity or CSS rules will blow this out of the water.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when creating dynamic HTML, XSS vulnerabilities can occur if not using quotes around dynamic attribute values.

Answer (score 15):

I do quote all attributes and will continue to do so. Primarily because it visually distinguishing where the attribute value starts and stops.

Additionally, it just makes sense for portability and compatibility reason. Though the quotes are optional in HTML[5], they are *not* optional in XHTML. You have a lot of tedious work to do if you need to convert your documents to XHTML (say, to display SVG on Webkit browsers).  We *really* don't need to dredge up the XHTML v. HTML debate, but it seems like too little hassle to not quote your attributes.

Saving a few bytes in the document body is nigh insignificant when you're downloading kilobytes and kilobytes of images and JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that because quotes are required in some instances you should use them consistently.  This makes your code cleaner and easier to read.  Switching between just creates unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 7):

I think one of the advantages to quoting all attributes is consistency.

If you're quoting some (with spaces or certain symbols), it feels nicer to me to quote all of them.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 was designed with backward compatibility in mind, so quoting attributes is okay. Many folks argue that since XHTML requires quotes it can't hurt to always include them. Personally I choose to quote. Required? No.

Here's some guidance I find reasonable. http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-syntax-style/