# Internet Explorer doesn't recognize css

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I made my webpage using Chrome and forgot to look at how my webpage loads in IE. When I open it in IE it looks like the browser isn't even using the css. Below is the code I placed in the `<head>` of my html files:

```
<!DOCKTYPE HTML>

 <html>

 <head>

 <title></title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel=StyleSheet href="largecw.css" TYPE="text/css" media=screen/>
 <script src="largecw.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: <link href="css-path" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> used to this

Comment: Note that you can use [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for problems with code (which will catch at least a problem with the docKtype declaration, in this case)

Comment: its <!DOCTYPE HTML>, not `<!DOCKTYPE HTML>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues **1**

```
<!DOCKTYPE HTML>
```

it should be DOCTYPE

Issue **2**

```
 <link rel=StyleSheet href="largecw.css" TYPE="text/css" media=screen/>
```

in this line **media=screen** is connected with **/** (**media=screen/**) and so it is not able to recognize media so better put it under quotes

```
 <link rel=StyleSheet href="largecw.css" TYPE="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `<link>` you use unquoted attributes and in combination with the closing `/>` the attribute value of `media` is set to `screen/`. This is an invalid media query so the CSS file is not loaded. Always quoting attributes prevents such mistakes, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495345/723769

To fix the issue quote all your attributes or add an additional space before the `/>` (or omit the `/` entirely since it is not required in HTML5).

Further you have a faulty doctype, which causes Quirksmode rendering in IE. It should be `<!doctype html>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

 <html>

 <head>

 <title></title>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./largecw.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script src="./largecw.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need " " wrapped around your rel="StyleSheet" and media="screen"

Chrome is not as strict as IE when it comes to loading head

Answer (score 0):

check specified css file's path, there might be chance that,resoucre not found at specified path.(if you have some separate folder to keep the css file,try to add its parent directory)

```
e.g. 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/largecw.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Check the path, once again.