# HTML/PHP input field - If $_POST is set, value = something, otherwise use placeholder?

Tags: php, html

**EDIT:** Guys, thank you all for quick answers, I appreciate them. Have my upvotes y'all.

I'm doing a simple registration form. I want some fields (nickname and email) to be pre-filled when the user made an invalid input (an unallowed character in the password field for example).

I tried to achieve it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="nickname" value=<?php if(isset($_POST["nickname"])) echo $_POST["nickname"]; ?> maxlength="30" required="required">
```

This only works when `$_POST["nickname"]` is set, otherwise it uses `maxlength="30"` as value.

Is there any way to make it use the placeholder when `$_POST["nickname"]` is empty?

I'm quite new to PHP, I am sorry if my question sounds stupid.
Also... apologies for my English.

Comment: you forgot to wrap your value value in quote marks. `...value="value" maxlength....` put the PHP code *inside* these html quote marks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - Importance of Double Quotes in HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827549/html-importance-of-double-quotes-in-html-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="nickname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["nickname"]) ? $_POST["nickname"] : ""; ?>" maxlength="30" required="required">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="nickname" value="<?php echo count($_POST["nickname"]) ? substr($_POST["nickname"], 0, 30):'';?>" maxlength="30" required="required">
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Your were missing quotes on value. Try this

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="nickname" value="<?php echo ( isset( $_POST["nickname"] ) ? $_POST["nickname"] : '' ); ?>" maxlength="30" required="required">
```