# django, how to display data with space in input box?

Tags: python, html, django

I am getting first name from user through an input box as "Catho Fransis" and saving it to my mysql db into a single field.

When i am trying to display this name in another text box in another page, only "Catho" get displayed. The words after a whitespace is ignored.

```
<td>
     <input disabled type="text" name="fname" style="width:235px;" value={{ user.first_name }}  > 
</td>
```

**How do i display the name?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around `{{ user.first_name }}`

```
<td><input disabled type="text" name="fname" style="width:235px;" value="{{ user.first_name }}"> </td>
```

For more info: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I thought that Since we are giving "{{ user.first_name }}" in value, The output is {{ user.first_name }}....