# Is there any difference for data-attribute=false with data-attribute="false" in html element?

Tags: html

I have data attribute in html element as `<button data-verified=false>Update</button>`. It have boolean value for data attribute.

Is there any difference with following element `<button data-verified="false">Update</button>` as the data-attribute is wrapped with double quotes.

Is boolean values are supported in html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boolean attributes are supported in HTML, but data-verified isn't one of them, no matter how it appears in the markup. `data-verified=false` and `data-verified="false"` both create an attribute of the type string and value "false", which if tested in JS as a boolean will be treated as *true*

This is only the case because `false` doesn't contain spaces. As a contrary example, `data-verified=not true` is invalid and not at all the same as `data-verified="not true"`

Comment: Is there any difference when dealing in javascript `if (!$('button').data('verified'))`?

Comment: @JustinJohn - No difference in JS. Libraries may do weird things, but the attribute with or without quotes will always be treated the same, since the JS will see only the DOM, not the original mark up. The DOMs are guaranteed to be identical.

Answer (score 3):

There are no differences in the values - however, **always** prefer to quote around attribute values, because:

- Looks cleaner
- Easier to maintain
- Every editor can deal with it easily
- It's a standard, nearly all HTML code examples you'll see use the value quoted

My answer corroborates from [Do you quote HTML5 attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a convention that attributes always have double quotes.

However. In jQuery, you can use the `.data()` method. It is smart enough to recognize booleans and numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that only the latter is allowed in XHTML. In HTML syntax, they both are allowed, and they are equivalent: the difference is lost when the HTML markup is parsed, and the DOM contains in both cases only the string `false`.

This follows from general principles in HTML and does not depend on the name of the attribute in any way.

“Boolean value” is a vague term. In HTML5, some attributes are called “boolean attributes”, but this is strongly misleading – especially since values `true` and `false`, far from being the only values allowed, aren’t allowed at all for such values. You need to read the specification of “boolean attributes” to see what they really are.

When you use `data-*` attributes, it is completely up to you what you use as values and how you process them.