# Using multiple quotes and double quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, quotes, double-quotes

I want to run a function inside a few quotes and double quotes but it's not working

```
document.getElementById("loggedin")
.innerHTML="welcome " + user + "<a onclick=deletecookie()> yes </a>";
```

Comment: Can't repro, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/q6nMn/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
document.getElementById("loggedin")
    .innerHTML="welcome " + user + "<a onclick='deletecookie()'> yes </a>";
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes) for why quotes should be included around HTML5 attributes.

Generally speaking though, it's better to bind something like this via a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) event listener  within your javascript code rather than injecting it into the DOM.  For example:

```
document.getElementById('loggedin')
    .innerHTML = "welcome " + user + "<a> yes </a>";
$('#loggedin').on('click', 'a', deletecookie);
```

This keeps your javascript isolated from your rendered HTML and makes it clearer how things are set up for future development.

Comment: Why are the quotation marks necessary? What is `$`?

Comment: Quotation marks are necessary for cross-browser support.  $ is jQuery, but I suppose you could do this with straight javascript as well.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what jQuery is and add a link. Which browsers have problems with unquoted attribute values? Quotation marks for attribute values are optional in HTML, unless the value contains invalid characters (such as a space).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use escaped double quotes, as shown below.

```
document.getElementById("loggedin").innerHTML="welcome " + user + "<a onclick=\"deletecookie()\"> yes </a>";
```

Comment: It's best if you show us a testcase. I created an example of the above code in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yvanavermaet/46gfM/) and it works fine.

Comment: it just says "welcome g%40yahoo.com yes" and when you click on yes, nothing happens

Comment: Open the console of your browser. The piece of code I wrote will output the message "delete cookie".

Comment: you mean i click ctrl + shift + j and paste exactly what you wrote??

Comment: You should update your piece of code (as written in your initial question) with my piece of code. If that doesn't work for you, then I believe you have an error somewhere else. Can you either explain in full what isn't working or provide an example?

Comment: it just says "welcome g%40yahoo.com yes" and when you click on yes, nothing happens

Comment: Have you written a javascript function called "deleteCookie"?