# Display a var in a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id=name>Whats your Name?: <input type="text" id="User">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="giveUser()"/>
<br> I dont know your Name </br>
</div>
<br>
<div id=P2>
Oh its <span id=User>Default</span>!
</div>
<script>

function giveUser() {
var User = document.getElementById("User").value;
console.log(User)
document.getElementById('User').innerHTML = User;
document.getElementById('name').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('P2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

</script>
```

Here i am asking the user there name through a textbox
but it won't display it in the span.

here is a fiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k04pvhug/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ID` attributes should be unique. Your `span` and `input` both have an ID of `User`

Change the `ID` of one and then try again. (https://jsfiddle.net/k04pvhug/1/)

In addition, you should enclose all your attributes with quotes (`"`). [It's not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes), but it looks cleaner ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the id's.

```
<span id="someid" />
```

Then JavaScript can access the DOM and set `innerHTML`
Also, P2 is a pre-defined setting, so it's not aviable as an id anyway. try `"paragraphTwo"` or something.

Answer (score 1):

Give the quotes around id and make sure that each attribute has the unique id 
like this

```
<span id="id" />
<p id="paragraph" />
<span id="span2" />
```

Comment: `id="id"` isn't a unique id either, and the DOM won't change.

Comment: @Wyatt ID name is of your's choice i just entered that it should be like this

Answer (score 0):

Use a different name for the var and the id

```js
function giveUser() {
        var User = document.getElementById("User").value;
        console.log(User)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = User ;
        document.getElementById('name').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('P2').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
```

```css
#P2 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=name>Whats your Name?:
    <input type="text" id="User">
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="giveUser()" />
    <br>I dont know your Name</br>
</div>
<br>
<div id=P2>Oh its <span id="demo">Default</span>!</div>
```