# target = "_blank" vs. target = _blank

Tags: html

Is there any difference between `target="_blank"` and `target=_blank` ?

Seems to have the same behavior, but just want to make sure if one is better to practice than the other (and why). I have always used quotes, but am reading the rails tutorial and realized Michael does not use them.

Comment: There is no difference functionally. It's generally agreed that best practice IS to use quotes. [Do you quote HTML5 attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes)

Comment: Both are valid but use of quotes adheres more to the XHTML specification. I'd say the best practice is with quotes.

Comment: What about target=blank without the underscore? That seems to work too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are equivalent.

The [HTML attribute syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) allows for quoted and unquoted attributes.

> In addition to the general requirements for attribute values, an unquoted attribute value has the following restrictions:
>
> - must not contain any literal space characters
> - must not contain any """, "'", "=", ">", "<", or "`", characters
> - must not be the empty string

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Always use first approach. **When you define an attribute, surround it's value with double quotes.** While both can work, second seems to be messy and inconsistent as well as can lead to some issues with older browsers.

Comment: This answer is just an opinion.