# Are quotation marks really necessary for attribute values in HTML tags?

Tags: html

I know that an attribute value in HTML needs quotation marks allow its attribute to modify an element, but I discovered that a value without quotations still appears to have valid syntax.

For example, both of these paragraph elements with and without quotations around the `style` value `color:#06c;` output the same blue text.

```html
<p style="color:#06c;">Some text</p>
<p style=color:#06c;>Some text</p>
```

Is it really necessary to have quotation marks around values in attribute/value pairs, or is it good practice to do so? I’m just curious to see if I can save a bit of coding time by omitting them.

Comment: Don't be lazy or sloppy. They aren't required but they're good form because they increase readability and crease potential errors.

Comment: Read this thread please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good practice and it's absolutely neccessary if you have an space inside:

```
 <p style="color: blue;"> <!-- GOOD -->
 <p style=color: blue> <!-- BAD!! -->
```

If you loves your health and your brain, write quotes ever, in all cases.