# not getting full value on textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i used .val() function in jquery to post value from textbox. when i alert i can see whole string .but when putting on a textbox only data before space is coming.anybody know this issue,please help
am sharing my code here

```
$('#add_input').click(function(){
var item = $('input[id="itemname"]').val();
i++;
 $('#dynamic1').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">\n\
<><td> <input type="text" name="serial_id" id="serial" value='+i+' ></td>\n\
<td><input type="text" name="item1[]"  value='+item+'></td></tr>');
```

in item texbox only getting first part of input value.

Comment: change `value='+item+'` to `value="'+item+'"`

Comment: @guradio  thank you so much dear. it worked. single quotes only takes first part?

Comment: adding `""` with concat the string properly taking it as entire string. glad to help mate happing coding :)

Comment: i am unable to understand the problem. his code seems working fine

Comment: @Anant concat of string not properly.when string has space

Comment: got it now. sorry to bother you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `item` has the string `hello` in it.

You have:

```
'... value='+item+'...'
```

When concatenated, it becomes:

```
value=hello
```

This is not proper HTML syntax. `hello` needs to be surrounded by quotes:

```
value="hello"
```

This means you need to change your code to:

```
'... value="'+item+'"...'
// --------^--------^----
```

In HTML5, quotes are optional for values that don't contain special characters or spaces. If they do, however, quotes are needed to identify where the value starts and ends. View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes) for more information.

Comment: @Hristiyhan thanks for detailed answer. guardio gave solution as comment firstly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
value='+item+'
```

In your case `'` was used to denote where your string starts and where it ends. `"` was used to denote where the HTML value starts and where it ends. The code was only specifying that `item` comes into the string dynamically, but it did not specify that it is an HTML value, thus the solution is

```
value="'+item+'"
```