# Can't use # in url to immediately go to 3 (e.g. index.html#3), why?

Tags: html, css, anchorpoint

First apologies, I am still a rookie and not a programmer, just a bit of self-tutored html-designer (more or less) and stuck with a problem for which I searched a solution for almost weeks.

I am building a glossary and have a scrollable column on the left with entries, each with a `<a href=index.html#302>blah </a>` linking to the main window with the same word followed by an explanation. The main window consists of a parent and a child. The child is merely a bit wider, 104%, to hide the y-scrollbar. Each entry is a fully designed div-element with `margin-bottom:300em;` to give the outer appearance of a pop-up when one clicks on an entry in the left window with words.

What troubles me is that I cannot jump to a word with say `<div class=ov id=203>` with `index.html#203` typed in the url, **nor can I use alt-arrow-left** to **go back in history** (I only see the # numbers change in the url on top but the page stays the same). The links in the left column work fine, though. It also works fine when I strip all surrounding windows and make it a bare html-page, without nested divs. Can anyone explain why this is so and what I can do to be able to jump to a # by typing a #-number in the url? I tried with adding several positioning-styles to the div-child with the text, but to no avail.

Many, many thanks!

Example:
Scrollable column left

```
<div class=trefw>
<a class=w href=#1>xxxxx </a>
<a class=w href=#2>ccccc </a>
<a class=w href=#3>dfasdfasd </a>
<a class=w href=#4>sdfzdfasdf </a>
</div>
```

Main text

```
<div class=context>
<div class=context1>
<div class=ov id=1><p3>xxxx</p3>xxxx</div>
<div class=ov id=2><p3>cccc</p3>cccccc</div>
<div class=ov id=3><p3>dfasdfasd </p3>dfasdfasd </div>
<div class=ov id=4><p3>sdfzdfasdf </p3>sdfzdfasdf </div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.trefw {
position:fixed;
top: 60px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 200px;
height:auto;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
z-index:499;
}

.context {
position:fixed;
top: 180px;
width:auto;
height:auto;
left: 210px;
right: 100px;
bottom: 30px;
overflow:hidden; 
z-index:70; 
}


.context1 {
position:relative;
width:104.5%;
height:100%;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

.ov {
font-family:basr;
text-align:left;
margin:20px;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:300em;
width:80%;
padding:28px;
border-radius:22px;
background-color:#fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 9px 9px 15px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
-moz-box-shadow: 9px 9px 15px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
box-shadow: 9px 9px 15px 0px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: In HTML versions before HTML5, `id` values cannot start with a number.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dorward/pen/mMyVoM — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto — Browsers didn't care though

Comment: `<a href id=302>blah </a>` — If you're going to have an `href` attribute, it needs a value. If you just want something to link to, don't use an `<a>` element. Link to a heading or a section or something appropriate instead.

Comment: In HTML5 you do not need `<a>` tags, any tag with an `id` attribute will do.

Comment: Anyhow, open your page in a browser, and look up your tag in its developer's tools. you will see, whether the id is interpreted, or not.

Comment: `<a id=302>` does not correspond to `index.html#3`, or is that just a typo here? Can you link to a page where this happens?

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto: How do I see if an id is interpreted or not? Btw, I tried with a prefix a before for instance 302, so a302, but no good.

Comment: @Mr Lister: yes it is a typo.

Comment: @Quentin, what do you mean with a value? O I see, I put the id instead of #302. My fault. But only here, at Stackoverflow, not in the webpage. I have it changed, thanks!

Comment: For the love of Cthulhu, please [always put quotes around your attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495345/3316645), pretty please? `<div class="ov">`

Comment: Fred, I think we need a [mcve] here. Otherwise, this would be a case of *can't reproduce*.

Comment: @domsson, I will work on an example. But for the love of Odin, alfather of all life, what is the purpose of quotes? I did never experience any better functionality. And with thousands of words and links it would diminish file size a lot. Of Javascript I understand, but plain markup and css, I just can't see its value.

Comment: Well, of course it boils down to preference, as both are valid. However, as soon as you have an attribute with two or more values, for example `class="foo bar"`, then you *need* to use quotes, which will lead to a mixed style. Most would argue that consistency is better, and therefore endorse "always use quotes". Also, it is less error prone: you might forget about the 'missing' quotes when adding a second value to an already existing attribute. :-)

Comment: It seems to be dependent on `position:static`, then it works alright. But how can I position the window like I want? With static the window is pulled to the left top side? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Fred Since quotes are always allowed, and sometimes they're mandatory, always putting them in is the sane choice and leaving them out as a matter of routine will one day cause big problems. For instance when your value contains `/>` or something. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/eju60268/).