# When to use quotes, brackets or nothing when passing props in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a Vue template, and passing props into components. I find it somewhat confusing to decide when I need brackets, quotes or none of those, to pass a variable down into a component. I have seen these three notations:

```
<status-view v-bind:total=total></status-view>

<status-view v-bind:total="total"></status-view>

<status-view v-bind:total="{total}"></status-view>
```

What exactly is the difference between these types of notations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first two examples are binding the `<status-view>` component's `total` prop to the value of `total` in the context of the current template's scope.

Your last example is binding the `<status-view>` component's `total` prop to the value of `{total}` in the context of the current template's scope.

In this case, `{total}` is the [ECMAScript2015 object initializer shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for `{ total: total }` (an object that has a key `total` with a value equal to the value of the `total` property).

To make it easier to reason about, let call the component `<child>`, the component's prop `foo` and the property we are binding `bar`.

---

#### With quotes:

`<child v-bind:foo="bar"></child>`

- binds the value of the `bar` property in the current scope to the child's `foo` prop
- anything within the quotes will be evaluated as a javascript expression. So `v-bind:foo="bar + 1"` (given `bar` equals `1`) would bind the value `2` to the child's `foo` prop.
- **I would recommend always binding a property value to a child component's prop this way**

---

#### Without quotes:

`<child v-bind:foo=bar></child>`

- also binds the value of the `bar` property in the current scope to the child's `foo` prop
- as Roy J pointed out, [attribute quotes are optional in HTLM5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes). So this will be evaluated exactly the same as above. For consistency's sake, I would still use quotes.

---

#### As an object:

`<child v-bind:foo="{bar}"></child>`

- binds an object `{ bar: bar }` to the child's `foo` prop
- for instace, if `bar` equaled `'test'`, the child's `foo` prop would be `{ bar: 'test' }`

---

[Here's the documentation for `v-bind`.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: Ah, of course `{ bar }` is just object shorthand :) So is there a reason to use quotes at all?

Comment: As I said in my answer I would always use quotes (sorry, I switched your order maybe that was confusing)

Comment: [Attribute quotes are optional in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes)

Comment: When you bind, you should bind to a single variable, not a very complicated javascript expression. So I disagree with putting quotes there because it enforces that you have simple variables there.